# WebXR content not playing in chrome 81

Tags: google-chrome, virtual-reality, webxr

I got a chrome 81 update in my android phone. After the update, the WebXR output is not playing. The "Enter VR" option is not appearing. On debugging I found that **navigator.xr.requestSession** request is pending and not getting resolved. Anyone else faced this issue? Is it a chrome issue?

Comment: The release notes suggest changes to WebXR - https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/04/nic81 - so most likely breaking changes.

Comment: Hi Stanly Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: This issue got fixed in the latest chrome. Now when we try to play the content, it shows installing google vr services and once installed, it will show the "Enter VR" button and it works as expected. Verified on chrome 81.0.4044.138